# Django rest remove password after creation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have user create serializer but still it is returning the password and c_password fields. How can I remove that to response.

```
class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    phone = CharField(label='Phone number')
    password = CharField(label='password')
    c_password = CharField(label='confirm passowrd')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'phone',
            'username',
            'password',
            'c_password'
        ]

        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True},
                        "c_password": {"write_only": True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        phone = validated_data['phone']
        username = validated_data['username']
        password = validated_data['c_password']

        user_obj = User(phone=phone, username=username)
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save()

        return validated_data

class UserCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

And I also tried to add the perform_create method and returned the custom Response object. but it is returning the serializer object with passwords.

Comment: what's your view like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning the validated data in your `create` method. If you only want the user object, simply return that. For example:

```
class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    phone = CharField(label='Phone number')
    password = CharField(label='password')
    c_password = CharField(label='confirm passowrd')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'phone',
            'username',
            'password',
            'c_password'
        ]

        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True},
                        "c_password": {"write_only": True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        phone = validated_data['phone']
        username = validated_data['username']
        password = validated_data['c_password']

        user_obj = User(phone=phone, username=username)
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save()

        return user_obj
```

Comment: Sorry c_password not included in the User model. I just added to get the confirm password. and if I return the user_obj. it is giving me an error c_password is not the user field. c_password is just to validate. I have declare c_password in the fields as well, if notit will give an error